# Remove element from nav bar

Tags: css, wordpress, nav

*(This is a question I would normally be able to ask the creators this wordpress theme, except that it's for a site I made long ago that was abandoned by the client...who has now reappeared and asked for some customisations! I'm no longer eligible for theme support so... hope you can help! Thanks!)*

I have a nav bar that had a search form build in. I'm trying to remove the search bar so the menu runs the whole way across.

Here's the CSS for the nav area.

[image: CSS]

Any suggestions?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: CSS is useless with the associated HTML.

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing the HTML, but I suspect .quick-search form { display:none} will remove the form. This is not the best way of doing it though - you would be better editing header.php to remove the search form from the rendered view altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything related to the search and put this

```
.nav-bar {width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the client wants search back I would use `.quick-search {display: none;}` and `.nav-bar: width: 100% !important`